# how can I save NSMutableArray into NSMutableArray so that previous data in NSMutableArray remain same?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to know that how can I add NSMutableArray in to an NSMutableArray so that previous data should not lost, and new data will be added on next indexes.

If you don't understand it then you can ask again to me, 
I will appraise the right answer.

my code is as below

```
-(void)setArray1:(NSMutableArray *)arrayValueFromNew

{

    self.myArray=arrayValueFromNew;

    myArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayValueFromNew];

    for(int i=0;i<[myArray2 count];i++)
    {
        [myArray addObject:[myArray2 objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

}
```

Comment: stop adding your code as a comment in every answer. add the code to your question instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, myArray and myArray2, both have same objects as you are assigning the arrayValueFromNew array to both. So it kind of doesn't make sense.

But to answer your question 'how to add one array to another?' do :

> [mutableArray1
>   addObjectsFromArray:array2];

EDIT:

this is how your method should look

```
-(void)setArray1:(NSMutableArray *)arrayValueFromNew

{

    if(!self.myArray)
    {
        self.myArray = arrayValueFromNew;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.myArray addObjectsFromArray:arrayValueFromNew];
    }
}
```

Your 'myArray must be initialized. You can initialize it in viewDidLoad or init:

> self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
>   initWithCapacity:1];

Comment: but will it erase the previous data in mutableArray1 or not, cz I dont want to delete the previous array which is saved in mutableArray1, any suggestion?

Comment: no it will not... thats why the method name is 'add'ObjectsFromArray.

Comment: not on this time, when next time when another array will come and this method will execute then it is erasing the previous value and just inserting the new value which in coming, try again

Comment: your code is wrong.. in the very first line you are assigning self.myArray with 'arrayValueFromNew' .. which is the new array... remove that line...

Comment: is it wrong ?                                                          -(void)setArray1:(NSMutableArray *)arrayValueFromNew {
 self.myArray = arrayValueFromNew;
 [myArray2 addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
 NSLog(@"%@", myArray2);

}

Comment: If I will remove self.myArray = arrayValueFromNew, then how do I utilize your way, give me code of two lines,

Comment: assuming your self.myArray is initialized just [self.myArray addObjectsFromArray: arrayValueFromNew]; is all you need. Just one line of code.....

Comment: This time it is not even saving the value sir, it is showing null in NSLog(@"%@", myArray);   now what should I do, but in self.myArray = arrayValueFromNew is working once, but second time when I assign value then it erase the previously stored values in myArray.

Comment: It is showing null, and my method is in AppDelegate.m, so now ViewDidLoad is there

Comment: the problem is you myArray is no initialized.. anyways.. check the edited code in my answer... this should work..

Comment: ok, I will do it and like ur answer if it will work perfectly

Comment: It is working but a small issue still there, complex one, but your answer is working well

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray array], *array2 = [NSMutableArray array];

// add some objects to the arrays

[array1 addObjectsFromArray:array2];

//array1 now contains all the objects originally in array1 and array2
```

Comment: no, it is not working, actual I am passing array from one method to another so logic is quit changed from normal passing values, any idea

Comment: this is my code, but yet not working, this is method of button, and taking two NSString, saving into an NSMutableArray and then calling method and passing value -(void)setArray1:(NSMutableArray *)arrayValueFromNew { self.myArray=arrayValueFromNew; myArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayValueFromNew];  for(int i=0;i<[myArray2 count];i++) { [myArray addObject:[myArray2 objectAtIndex:i]]; }

Comment: Please edit the question and make it more clear what you are trying to do. Your code does not make any sense.

Comment: @Joe BLow and Jakob Egger, Sir I have edited the question, now see it

Answer (score 0):

This will work,

```
NSMutableArray *mutarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: array1]
```

Comment: but by doing this, the previous values in *mutaarr will be erased, I want to continue new values in array, and previous values should remain same.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<[aray1 count];i++) { [array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]]; }

Comment: this is my code, but yet not working, this is method of button, and taking two NSString, saving into an NSMutableArray and then calling method and passing value                                               -(void)setArray1:(NSMutableArray *)arrayValueFromNew {
 self.myArray=arrayValueFromNew;
 myArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayValueFromNew]; 
 
 for(int i=0;i<[myArray2 count];i++) {
  [myArray addObject:[myArray2 objectAtIndex:i]]; 
}

Comment: please check that you have allocated myArray

Comment: Even I don't allocate, same problem is there, once I can assign array, but next time it won't work, and replace the value that was previously stored.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want a new copy of the old array. There is a handy function for that

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [oldArray mutableCopy];
```

Remember that you've used copy in getting this array so you are responsible for managing the memory of newArray

**EDIT**

What is your code doing?

```
-(void)setArray1:(NSMutableArray *)arrayValueFromNew                      //1

{

    self.myArray=arrayValueFromNew;                                       //2

    myArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayValueFromNew];  //3

    for(int i=0;i<[myArray2 count];i++)
    {
        [myArray addObject:[myArray2 objectAtIndex:i]];                   //4
    }

}
```

1. This looks like a setter for a property `array1`
2. You are setting the property 'array' to `arrayValueFromNew`. Since I don't know whether this property has been declared with `retain` or `copy` I don't know whether array is a pointer to `arrayValueFromNew` or a pointer to a copy of `arrayValueFromNew`
3. You set myArray2 to be a new array that contains the objects of `arrayValueFromNew`
4. For each object in `myArray2` (which are the objects from `arrayValueFromNew`. see point 3) you add this object to `myArray`. Assuming `myArray` is an `NSMutableArray` it started with the objects from `arrayValueFromNew` which you have now added again. It contains each item in `arrayValueFromNew` twice.

Comment: but when I need it again and again, then what is your suggestion, I don't want to erase old data in my array, so like if 5 indexes are full, then next value should add to 6th index, hope u get what i want

Comment: Unfortutately, no, I don't understand what you want. You get a copy of the original array and then you can add objects to whatever array you want.